# Install on Drupal 7 on Synology

Tags: drupal, permissions, install

I have a

- Synology DiskStation NAS: DS918+, running DSM 6.2
- Running the Synology MariaDB-10 package
- Running Synology Package Drupal on it (vs 7.58 as of today). Developed by the Drupal-investigator Dries Buytaert and provided by Synology)
- Only one Drupal user: the administrator (I checked the privileges in the drupal UI and in the database as well)
- Tried to install Civicrm 4.7.31 on it, using:
  http://192.168.1.110/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php
- all drupal/civicrm directories/files have same ownership (http:http)

It keeps giving me the "*You don't have permission to access this page*" message.

Question: anybody familiar with installing civicrm in this Synology environment? or with similar permission problems in another environment?

As work-around I have in mind to create a VM (ubuntu 16.04, LAMP) and do a complete "manual"install of Drupal 7.58 and civicrm 4.7.31 but that's a lot of extra work and overhead. So I hope to avoid that.

Thanks in advance,

Kind regards, Hans Troost

Comment: Does it have to be drupal? Does synology come with joomla or wordpress?